# C, function in switch case

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

I'm trying to generate random matrix or filling it by user of the program with switch case which has functions in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void randomly(int **matrix, int r, int c)
{
    int i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            matrix[r][c] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}

void fill_normal(int **matrix, int r, int c)
{
    int i, j;
    printf("\nEnter matrix elements :\n");
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            printf("ENTER FOR --> [%d,%d] : ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix(int **matrix, int r, int c)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");   /*new line after row elements*/
    }
}

int main()
{
    int r, c;
    printf("Enter the rows and cols of matrix:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &r,&c);


    int **matrix = malloc(r * c * sizeof(int));

    int o;
    printf("Enter 1 if you want to generate the numbers randomly:\n");
    printf("Enter 2 if you want to enter the number by yourself:\n");
    scanf("%d",&o);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    switch(o)
    {
        case 1:
            randomly(matrix,r,c);
            print_matrix(matrix,r,c);
            break;
        case 2:
            fill_normal(matrix,r,c);
            print_matrix(matrix,r,c);
            break;
        default:
            printf("!!!WRONG OPERATOR!!!");
            break;
    }
    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

For Case 1: I see nothing and the program stops without showing anything.
For Case 2: I start to filling the matrix but on matrix[3][1] program crushes
I do not know can I do guys codes in fucntions are corret but they doesnt work
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Change `matrix[r][c] = rand() % 10; ` to `matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;`

Comment: See this link to know about dynamic memory allocation of 2D arrays : https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamically-allocate-2d-array-c/amp/

Answer (score 3):

`matrix` is not a true 2D array but a pointer to a pointer.  As such, it can point to the first element of an array of `int *`, each of which can point to the first element of an array of `int`.

So when you use `matrix[i][j]`, the first subscript dereferences the `int *` array, and the second dereferences an `int` array.  But you never set `matrix[i]` to a valid pointer value before referencing `matrix[i][j]`, so you get [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Instead of pointing `matrix` to a memory block for `r*c` value of type `int`, it first needs to point to `r` elements of type `int *`, then each of those point to `c` element of type `int`:

```
int i;
int **matrix = malloc(r * sizeof(int *));
for (i=0; i<r; i++) {
    matrix[i] = malloc(c * sizeof(int));
}
```

Then to clean it up you do the opposite:

```
for (i=0; i<r; i++) {
    free(matrix[i]);
}
free(matrix);
```

Also, you're using the wrong array indices in `randomly`:

```
matrix[r][c] = rand() % 10;
```

You instead want:

```
matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void randomly(void *matrix, size_t r, size_t c)
{
    size_t i, j;
    int (*m)[r][c] = matrix;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            (*m)[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
}

void fill_normal(void *matrix, size_t r, size_t c)
{
    size_t i, j;
    int (*m)[r][c] = matrix;
    printf("\nEnter matrix elements :\n");
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            printf("ENTER FOR --> [%d,%d] : ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&(*m)[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix(void *matrix, size_t r, size_t c)
{
    size_t i, j;
    int (*m)[r][c] = matrix;
    for(i=0; i<r; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<c; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",(*m)[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");   /*new line after row elements*/
    }
}

int main()
{
    int r = 7, c = 10;
    printf("Enter the rows and cols of matrix:\n");
    //scanf("%d%d", &r,&c);


    int *matrix = malloc(r * c * sizeof(int));

    int o;
    printf("Enter 1 if you want to generate the numbers randomly:\n");
    printf("Enter 2 if you want to enter the number by yourself:\n");
    //scanf("%d",&o); 
    o = 1;
    printf("o = %d\n\n\n", o);
    switch(o)
    {
        case 1:
            randomly(matrix,r,c);
            print_matrix(matrix,r,c);
            break;
        case 2:
            fill_normal(matrix,r,c);
            print_matrix(matrix,r,c);
            break;
        default:
            printf("!!!WRONG OPERATOR!!!");
            break;
    }
    free(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```